# Can Bottles be Pasteurized Lying on Their Sides?

Tags: carbonation, pasteurization

I want to bottle a sweet cider with carbonation. In every process to achieve this one step is to pasteurize the bottles in a pot of hot water, kept to a specific temperature after the bottles have the carbonation level you desire.

Can you do this heating process on bottles laying on their sides? Can they be stacked, even with a rag between the layers?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the question here would be, can your caps maintain a proper seal if submerged in ~190F water for 10 minutes or so?

I don't know if you'll be able to figure this out with real data as the cap manufacturer will probably outright advise against this (if you could get ahold of them).

Personally- I probably wouldn't do it as I have a sneaking suspicion this would affect the seal. But it probably depends on time soaked, temperature, cap type, etc.

Perhaps best is to try it with a single bottle and try to determine if the cap is loosened afterwords once it's cooled.